# Update application xdk

Tags: intel-xdk

I created an application with intel xdk
I changed the project location and generated a new apk
but the installation of the new apk didn't override the older apk  with the same certificate
I also updated the version
I got an error: "Application not installed".
what can be the problem?

Comment: Are you talking about attempting to update to the store or updating via a side-load to your device? If side-loading to your device, for testing, try uninstalling the old version and then installing the new version.